# Windows Phone 7.8 WideTile Image not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I have tried both solutions below and they both have the same result. the tile is created but the image doesn't appear. I am able to set the title and other properties but when I use this solution it doesn't work. I have verified the image path and that it was in the build. Any Ideas?

```
public static void UpdateFlipTile(
            Uri wideBackgroundImage, 
            Uri wideBackBackgroundImage)
{
   if (IsTargetedVersion)
   {
  // Get the new FlipTileData type.
  Type flipTileDataType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone");

  // Get the ShellTile type so we can call the new version of "Update" that takes the new Tile templates.
  Type shellTileType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");

  // Loop through any existing Tiles that are pinned to Start.
  foreach (var tileToUpdate in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
  {
     // Look for a match based on the Tile's NavigationUri (tileId).

        // Get the constructor for the new FlipTileData class and assign it to our variable to hold the Tile properties.
        var UpdateTileData = flipTileDataType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null);

        // Set the properties. 
        SetProperty(UpdateTileData, "WideBackgroundImage", wideBackgroundImage);
        SetProperty(UpdateTileData, "WideBackBackgroundImage", wideBackBackgroundImage);


        // Invoke the new version of ShellTile.Update.
        shellTileType.GetMethod("Update").Invoke(tileToUpdate, new Object[] { UpdateTileData });

            break;

      }
   }

}

private static void SetProperty(object instance, string name, object value)
{
   var setMethod = instance.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetSetMethod();
   setMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
}
```

And I also tried this solution

```
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(7, 10, 8858))
{
    var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
    var flipTileData = new FlipTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Icons/MediumLogo.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Icons/WideLogo.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            };
    tile.Update(flipTileData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the image sizes correct?
Did you set the images' build property to "Content"?
Is it maybe necessary to set all properties in FlipTileData?

Comment: I considered that it may be the image sizes, but I don't know the required sizes. I did set the build property to content with no luck. I Also set it to always copy. I will try setting all the properties next but the title property works without them all being set so I don't have much faith in that approach haha.

Comment: Tile sizes here => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Tilesizesandresolutions

Comment: For some reason the Build property wasn't setting to content even though it said it was. Once I figured this out I just removed the image from the project, re-added it then set its build property to Content and Always Copy. Works like a charm. Thanks